# User Auditing activity in prime faces

Tags: jsf, auditing

How do I get the header fields ?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AI1Nj.png)

I.e. Me need get message label 'Наименование' for entity field.
I do use hibernate and i do know what exist Hibernate ORM Envers.
I use reflection for get entity fields name and value.
Or write for every field annotation with label value

How do you resolve that problem?

Comment: this is not realy jsf related! And I do not really understand the problem

Comment: @Kukeltje: OP want to log entity change events and basically wants a generic way to grab the i18n label associated with the property for some reason. I'd say, this makes no sense, just logging the property name is sufficient. Then in the place where you present the log results, you already have entity and property name at hands, you can just do the i18n thing in the view over there based on that information. Ah well.

Comment: @BalusC: I understood the basic issue, but the part I did not understand was/is what you describe: _"wants a generic way to grab the i18n label associated with the property for some reason. I'd say, this makes no sense,"_. But I was working from my phone and I should have taken a little more time to explain (typing on a desktop still is easier)

Comment: @Kukeltje: What will make in view? I don't understand

Comment: You should do nothing in the view. Like BalusC wrote, determine the corresponding label in the backend (there most likely is something like a resource bundle, that based on the property/field name and a language can determine the label)